# IServiceProvider that is not registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

When the application starts the error occurs

> The constructor of type ImportExportController contains the parameter
> with name 'serviceProvider' and type IServiceProvider that is not
> registered. Please ensure IServiceProvider is registered, or change
> the constructor of ImportExportController

My code

```
public class ImportExportController : BaseController
{
   private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

   public ImportExportController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
     _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
   }
}
```

for the injection of dependencies I'm using the Simple Injector

The error happens in the **container.Verify();**

```
private static void Register(Container container)
{
   _container = container;
   container.Register<IXmlServices, XmlServices>();
   container.Verify();
}
```

I'm using _serviceProvider here

```
foreach (var element in productsToImport)
{​​​​​​​
   using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
   {​​​​​​​
      var app = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IImportApp>();
      var task = Task.Run(() => app.ImportData(element, UserName, ImportID, PricesCurrencies));
      listTask.Add(task);
   }​​​​​​​
}​​​​​​​
Task.WaitAll(listTask.ToArray());
```

Comment: What is the exact function of the `IServiceProvider` you want to inject? Please show how it is used and what your intentions are. The answer to your question depends on those details. For instance, you you intend to resolve instances from it? Do you expect it to forward calls to the Simple Injector `Container`? Why does your controller need a Service Locator?

Comment: Which Simple Injector version are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to use the parallel but inside it i have the npoco

Comment: tried using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())

Comment: but in the project where I do the dependency injections this with .net 4.5 and it is not supported by Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions

Comment: CreateScope is an extension method from MS.DI. This will not create a Simple Injector scope, if that's what you're aiming at. But it's still not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i'm trying to make inserts in the database in parallel

Comment: Perhaps this does help: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html#multi-threaded-applications

Comment: But either way, Simple Injector does _not_ allow injecting an ISeviceProvider. Instead, you should inject `Container`.

Comment: I added my code here

Comment: This section explains how to do scoping in Simple Injector: https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#scoped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register the `IServiceProvider`, in the same way you did for `IXmlServices`.

```
container.Register<IServiceProvider, ServiceProvider>();
```

Given that, the `ServiceProvider` is a class that implements interface `IServiceProvider`.

Comment: Ack, you beat me to it. I was half way through my answer... :-)